# Visual Basic -smtpException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

been trying to send emails through visual basic but running into a problem. Everytime i run i either get the error "smtpException was unhandled" or "Operation timed out" any help would be appreciated

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1


Dim mail As New MailMessage()
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("testemail1@gmail.com", "password")
    SmtpServer.Port = 465
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    mail.To.Add("testemail@hotmail.co.uk")
    mail.From = New MailAddress("testemail1@gmail.com")
    mail.Subject = "Match Reminder"
    mail.Body = "A reminder you have an upcoming match"
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
End Sub
```

Comment: anyone got any help?

Comment: Hi. I think guys need more information to figure out what is happening. You need to check your environment to know the origin of the smtp exception. Make sure that the mail service is working, that you gave the right password and parameters, etc. Very difficult to figure it out when one has no access to your environment.